# Determining by hand whether a big matrix is positive definite

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, positive-definite

Consider the following matrix:
$$A = \begin{pmatrix} 
3 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -1 \\ 
-1 & 3 & -1 & 0 & -1 & 0 \\ 
0 & -1 & 3 & -1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & -1 & 3 & -1 & 0 \\ 
0 & -1 & 0 & -1 & 3 & -1 \\ 
-1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -1 & 3 
\end{pmatrix}$$

It was part of an exam question, where one needed to prove that it is **symmetric positive definite** in order to prove that both the Gauss-Seidel and Jacob method converge. I was not able to solve this by hand.

How can one approach this in the most efficient way in a time-sensitive setting? I personally tried to just calculate the eigenvalues, but failed because of the $6 \times 6$ determinant. Another approach would be to compute the determinants of the principal minors, but this also would be a lot of work for this small of a part of an exam.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To show that $A$ is positive semidefinite, it suffices to note that $A$ is symmetric and [diagonally dominant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diagonally_dominant_matrix) with non-negative diagonal entries. From there, we could row-reduce to verify that $A$ is invertible.

Another approach: we can write $A$ as a sum
$$
A = \begin{pmatrix} 
2 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -1 \\ 
-1 & 2 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & -1 & 2 & -1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & -1 & 2 & -1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & -1 & 2 & -1 \\ 
-1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -1 & 2 
\end{pmatrix} + 
\begin{pmatrix} 
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & -1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 
\end{pmatrix}.
$$
It is easy to compute the eigenvalues of both matrices to verify that they are positive semidefinite (the first matrix in particular is [circulant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circulant_matrix)). It follows that $A$ is the sum of positive semidefinite matrices and is therefore positive semidefinite.

In fact, we could also use this decomposition to see that $A$ is positive definite.  For positive semidefinite matrices $B,C$, we have
$$
\ker(B + C) \subset \ker(B) \cap \ker(C).
$$
In this case, the two matrices being added have distinct $1$-dimensional kernels so that $\ker(B) \cap \ker(C) = \{0\}$.

Comment: Are you sure? In my lecture we learned, that A has to be **strictly** diagonally dominant, which means that $\lvert a_{ii}\rvert > \sum_{j\neq i} \lvert a_{ij} \rvert$, which isn't fulfilled by this matrix. Is this wrong?

Comment: @Katharina you're right; I missed that you needed to show that $A$ is positive definite as opposed to positive semidefinite.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom In our notes it was mentioned that strict diagonal dominance is rare, and thus a different criterion was given, in that if at least one row is "strictly $>$", the rest can be only $\geq$ and the methods will still converge, but only if the matrix is irreducible. Which makes me think that this is what they wanted me to do in the exam, but we never learned any algorithm to check if a matrix is irreducible. But just row reducing after checking for it being semi-definite seems to be something that I could do in such short of time, so I will do that in the second exam try! Thanks!

Comment: @Katharina here's an algorithm that works for symmetric matrices: produce an [adjacency matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjacency_matrix) using the off-diagonal entries (putting in a $1$ for any non-zero entry) and draw the graph associated with this adjacency matrix.  The matrix is irreducible if and only if the graph is connected.

Comment: @CarlChristian thanks for catching that

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Thank you again for your help! Considering that this type of problem appeared multiple times in the exam (matrices being only weakly diagonal dominant), this will help me get a much better grade next time. Thanks.